# Linq query - dynamic data types

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query working nicely to aggregate values from a DataTable.

The idea is that a user can select one of a list of fields, and the linq aggregates data according to the field selected.

**p_measure** is a string variable denoting the name of a field selected.

However, in it's current form, this all only works when the selected field is of data type 'float' in the source table.
If the user selects an 'int' ... then I get a cast exception thrown.

So the question is, how do i make this code 'dynamic' to handle the varying datatypes ?

```
// Table for receiving aggregated results 
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(p_dimension, typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add(p_measure, typeof(Double));

// Query to perform aggregation
DataTable query = (from r in rootDT.AsEnumerable()
                   group r by new
                           {
                              Dimension = r.Field<string>(p_dimension)
                           } into g
                             select new
                           {
                              Dimension = g.Key.Dimension,
                              Measure = g.Sum(x => x.Field<double>(p_measure))
                            }
                         ).Aggregate(table, (dt, r) => dt.Rows.Add(r.Dimension,r.Measure); return dt; });
```

I can handle the type in the "new DataTable" declaration (line 4):

```
table.Columns.Add(p_measure, typeof(Double));
```

by generating & setting a variable of type Type, thus :

```
table.Columns.Add(p_measure, myTypeVariable);
```

But I am at a loss how to handle this one:

```
x.Field<double>(p_measure)
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: have you tried `x.Field<dynamic>`

Comment: Are you doing this against a database? If yes, then are you aware you are pulling whole table into memory and doing all the querying in memory?

Comment: It's a datatable already in memory.  Simply the user want to see ALL the records in a dataGridView, and a chart representing grouped totals alongside.   I understand that if it were a large recordset, I should look at doing the heavy lifting at the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result to always be a `double` you can use

```
Measure = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x[p_measure]))
```

Then it will only on any numeric type, or string columns whose values can all be parsed to a `double`.

Comment: Brilliant !!   Thank you.   Only just started using Linq for the first time, and think it's confused me more that it should have.  For some reason I assumed a standard cast wouldn't work within a query - kick self now !

Comment: @user3379697 Glad it works.  To be clear - it's not a "cast".  It's a "conversion".  Conversions convert one type to another type; casts just change how the variable is treated when binding method calls.  You can't "cast" an `int` to a `double` because they are not compatible data types - the underlying memory is different.